# How to make a listview with headers and subheaders of some groups

Tags: android

Basically, I want something like below:

[image]

How can you make it possible with listview or gridview or even recyclerview?

Comment: have you try anything?

Comment: @Sohail Zahid : i tried and could just make single groups with expandable listview but cant get the idea of how to add subheaders to those groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your desire result using this [**Tutorial**](http://techlovejump.com/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/)

It will produce result like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks bro. ATM I was actually looking this solution as i found it.